# Old anime techniques

Tags: anime-production, resources

Tell me, what tools and techniques were used to draw the old anime, for example, this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What interests me is with what instrument and on which paper the character and background were drawn, how they were combined. The whole production process from the technical side.

Comment: This is a very broad and lengthy topic for someone to attempt to. It does not fulfill our site policy on out of universe list questions. Please consider narrowing your scope as to not make potentially answerers write a book on the topic.

Comment: A link to an already written book / article is suitable for me. Or at least tell me which tools were used to draw these pictures. Watercolors, acrylics or something else. Background and characters separately.

Comment: Different productions have different techniques depending on staff and budget. There's no one size fits all solution, unfortunately. We ask you to be a bit more specific as we can't possibly cover all the bases at once. We also don't know what you consider "old". Simply speaking some have been purely cel animation others are a blend of CGI and digitally converted and painted hand drawn cels.

Comment: I cited several images as an example. I am currently interested in them.